# Proof of satisfaction given the same free variable interpretation

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

I am reading Enderton's *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* ([here](http://agnigarh.tezu.ernet.in/~zubin/isc/extra/MathematicalIntroductionToLogic-Enderton.pdf) a link to its second edition) and I am not sure I understand this proof, could anyone help please?
[image]

What I don't understand is what the structure of the proof is: specifically what the induction is being done on, and what the induction hypothesis is.

It seems to me that the induction is being done on the complexity of the formula, ie. count of logical operator. Atomic formula, which by def has no logical operator, naturally becomes the base case, with $\lnot$ and $\to$ being the inductive steps.

The $\forall$ case is the most confusing. By assumption $s_1(x|d)$ agrees with $s_2(x|d)$ - that I understand. But then Enderton cites the inductive hypothesis as the justification of $\psi$ being satisfied by $s_1(x|d)$ iff it is satisfied by $s_2(x|d)$ - this only seems possible if the induction is done on the complexity of the formula, otherwise I don't see how he can legitimately cite the hypothesis here.

---

Satisfaction as explained in the book:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: As you say, Case 1 (the base case) is obvious, because the two functions $s_1$ and $s_2$ assign the same objects to the same variables: thus, the result will be the same. For 2 e 3, there is nothing to prove.

Comment: The only "interesting" case is that of $\forall$. Here we have again $s_1$ and $s_2$ agree on the free vars of $\varphi = \forall x \psi$. When we remove the quantifier, we have (at most) one new free var : $x$. But if we consider $s_1(x|d)$ and $s_2(x|d)$, they again agree on all free vars of $\psi$, that was all those of $\varphi$ plus $x$.

Comment: Now consider $s_1$: if it satisfies $\varphi$, this means that - by the specification of *satisfaction* - that $s_1(x|d)$ satisfies $\psi$, for every $d$. Now apply induction hypotheses, due to the fact that $\psi$ has lower complexity than $\varphi$ : $s_2(x|d)$ satisfies $\psi$, because it agrees on all free var of $\psi$. But this holds for every $d$, and thus $s_2$ satisfies $\forall x \psi$. But $s_2$ agrees with $s_1$ on all free vars of $\varphi$, and it's done.

Comment: Now repeat starting with $s_2$, and we have the **iff**.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, this is a very good complement to Taroccoesbrocco's answer. Just one question: '$\vDash s_2(x|d)$ holds for every $d$' - is this because, given an arbitrary $d$, we have $\vDash s_1(x|d)$, but by IH $\vDash s_2(x|d)$, so this in turn holds for every $d$?

Comment: We have (omitting for simplicity $\mathfrak A$)  $\varphi [s_1]= (\forall x \psi )[s_1] \text { iff } \vDash \psi [s_1(x|d)]$ for every $d$. By Ind Hypo this amounts to $\vDash \psi [s_2(x|d)]$ for every $d$. Because for every formula of lower complexity of $\varphi$ (and $\psi$ is one) we have that $\vDash \psi [s_1] \text { iff } \vDash \psi [s_2]$.

Comment: 'By IH this amounts to $\vDash \psi[s_2(x|d)$ for every $d$': so we are applying the IH on the '$\vDash \psi[s_1(x|d)$ for every $d$' to get $\vDash \psi[s_2(x|d)$ for every $d$? The 'every $d$' is tripping me up a bit here, presumably this is NOT the same as a $\forall$ (ie part of the meta-language), so it doesn't add to $\psi$'s complexity and thus we can still apply IH (to $\vDash \psi[s_1(x|d)$ for every $d$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the proof of theorem 22A is by induction on (the complexity of) the formula $\varphi$.

There are two subtleties in this proof.

1. In the base case, where $\varphi$ is an atomic formula, the proof uses the following lemma: given a term $t$, if $s_1$ and $s_2$ agree at all variables in $t$ then $\overline{s_1}(t) = \overline{s_2}(t)$. As mentioned in the text, this lemma should be proved separately, by induction on the (complexity of the) term $t$.
2. In the inductive step where $\varphi = \forall x \, \psi$, the induction hypothesis says that if $s'_1$ and $s'_2$ are two functions from $V$ to $|\mathfrak{A}|$ that agree at all free variables in $\psi$, then $\mathfrak{A}$ satisfies $\psi$ with $s_1'$ iff $\mathfrak{A}$ satisfies $\psi$ with $s_2'$. Unfortunately, you cannot apply the induction hypothesis to $\psi$ with $s_1$ and $s_2$ because $x$ is not a free variable of $\varphi = \forall x \, \psi$ but it might be a free variable in $\psi$ and we do not have any hypothesis about the behavior of $s_1$ and $s_2$ in $x$ (said differently, the formula $\psi$ is smaller than $\varphi$ but the hypothesis are not satisfied by $\psi$ with $s_1$ and $s_2$). But the functions $s_1(x \mid d)$ and $s_2(x \mid d)$ agree at all the free variables of $\psi$, hence we can apply the induction hypothesis to $\psi$ with $s_1(x \mid d)$ and $s_2(x \mid d)$: therefore, $\mathfrak{A}$ satisfies $\psi$ with $s_1(x \mid d)$ iff $\mathfrak{A}$ satisfies $\psi$ with $s_2(x \mid d)$. By definition of satisfaction, this means that $\mathfrak{A}$ satisfies $\varphi = \forall x \, \psi$ with $s_1$ iff $\mathfrak{A}$ satisfies $\varphi$ with $s_2$.

Comment: I understand that $s_1(x|d)$ and $s_2(x|d)$ agree on all free variables of $\psi$, and because complexity of $\psi < \varphi$ we can apply IH, so whether $x$ is free or not in $\psi$ is irrelevant. But shouldn't $x$ be free in $\psi$? Because say if $\varphi = \forall x Fx$, then $x$ in $\psi$ is freed from the $\forall$ and thus is a free variable? I don't see how $x$ maybe not free in $\psi$.

Comment: @DanielMak - Suppose $\varphi$ is the formula $\forall x \forall x \, x \!=\! x$ (in a language with identity, but it is not neccessary). Then, $\psi$ is the formula $\forall x \, x \!=\! x$ and $x$ is not free in $\psi$.